# System.out.println() not working inside recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

This is the Java code I wrote (**Logic** is that you can get a free soda bottle, if you exchange 5 empty soda bottles). Feel free to criticize or feedback for a better approach.

```
package com.eanurag.practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SodaBottleProblem {

    private int totalSodaBottle = 0;
    private int freeSodaBottle = 0;
    private int remainingBottle = 0;

    public int numberOfBottles(int originalNumberOfBottles) {
        freeSodaBottle = originalNumberOfBottles;
        while (freeSodaBottle % 5 >= 5) {
            if (freeSodaBottle % 5 == 0) {
                freeSodaBottle = freeSodaBottle / 5;
                System.out.println("The Free Bottle count now is: "
                        + freeSodaBottle);
                totalSodaBottle = totalSodaBottle + freeSodaBottle;
                System.out.println("The total Bottle count now is: "
                        + totalSodaBottle);
                numberOfBottles(freeSodaBottle);
            }

            else if (originalNumberOfBottles % 5 != 0) {
                remainingBottle = freeSodaBottle % 5;
                System.out
                        .println("The remaining count is: " + remainingBottle);
                freeSodaBottle = freeSodaBottle - (remainingBottle);
                System.out.println("The Free Bottle count now is: "
                        + freeSodaBottle);
                numberOfBottles(freeSodaBottle);
            }
        }
        totalSodaBottle = totalSodaBottle + (freeSodaBottle + remainingBottle)
                / 5;
        System.out.println("Final value before return is:" + totalSodaBottle);
        return totalSodaBottle;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SodaBottleProblem sd = new SodaBottleProblem();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the original number of Soda bottles");
        int originalNumberOfBottles = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Total number of bottles you can get: "
                + sd.numberOfBottles(originalNumberOfBottles));
        sc.close();
    }

}
```

**Issue:** I am quite puzzled to understand as to why `System.out.println()` calls inside recursive method *numberOfBottles* are not working at all. This is the **output** in console:

```
Enter the original number of Soda bottles
77
Final value before return is:15
Total number of bottles you can get: 15
```

Comment: Are you sure the loop is actually running?  I'm pretty sure `freeSodaBottle % 5 >= 5` never returns true.

Comment: `freeSodaBottle % 5 >= 5`

Comment: Also, this is basic debugging: check your assumptions. Print intermediate, calculated values. Trace execution by hand or using a debugger. Pretend you're the computer.

Answer (score 2):

`while (freeSodaBottle % 5 >= 5)`

This line always be false, A modulo B always be less than B

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your code, an int modulo 5 can never be greater or equal 5 so the while loop is never entered

Answer (score 0):

condition (freeSodaBottle % 5 >= 5) will always be false